# What is the 'client' parameter in google places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Some people load the google places api with a client parameter, example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&client=CLIENT_PARAMETER_VALUE&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
```

*What is this parameter stand for ? Is it used in relation with a quota limitation ?*

I have checked the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) and there is nothing about the client parameter or about quota usage limitations.

Thank you in advance for your feedbacks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the client parameter is used by people with the Google Maps API for Business licence, which gives a variety of benefits: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing